# Javascript replace content and refresh it with new content which new content from outerHTML

Tags: javascript

Is possible to refresh page with new content which new content from outerHTML? I'm having problem which I want to refresh page until 2 seconds, proccess 0-2 seconds to get new HTML with innerHTML and etc. But after I get new content from outerHTML. I difficulty to refresh this content with HTML from outerHTML.

Below my example code:

```
<script>
    // code blablabla to get new content. This has been fix code, and below code to start refresh page with outerHTML.
    window.onload = function() {
        tes();
    };

    function tes() {
        var htmlAll = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
        setTimeout(function(){howCodeRefresh()}, 2000);
        function howCodeRefresh() {
            // how code to refresh page and replace all content with variable htmlAll
        };
    };
</script>
```

My question: Is possible to do it? If yes, how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are not very clearly to explain your question,you can try ajax in jquery to solve your question.Here is a basic demo:

```
    <div id = "target"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = loadHtml;
        function loadHtml(){
             $.get("your/server/page.html",function(response){
                   $("#target").html(response);     //Here is your html response
             },'html');
         }
    </script>
```

[Here is more document for jquery ajax.](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)